# Cannot find function "echart" in R after successfully installing the recharts package

Tags: r

my code:

```
install.packages(
  'recharts',
  repos = c('http://yihui.name/xran', 'http://cran.rstudio.com')
)
library(recharts)
echart(iris, ~Sepal.Length, ~Sepal.Width, series = ~Species)
```

The error is:

> Error: could not find function "echart"

Comment: @BondedDust Yes, but the OP probably followed the instruction on [this page](https://github.com/yihui/recharts).

Comment: I sent a "heads up" to Yihui.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, there is no `echart` function in `recharts` package when you install it with:

```
install.packages('recharts', repos = c('http://yihui.name/xran', 'http://cran.rstudio.com'))
```

This installs the version `0.0.1` of `recharts`

```
library(recharts)
echart(iris, ~Sepal.Length, ~Sepal.Width, series = ~Species)
Error: could not find function "echart"
```

But if you install the same package with:

```
devtools::install_github("yihui/recharts")
```

This installs the version `0.0.3` of `recharts`

```
library(recharts)
echart(iris, ~Sepal.Length, ~Sepal.Width, series = ~Species)
```

It works

[image]